# How to divide string by comma into new columns?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I researched a lot and didn't find exactly what I am trying to do. I am trying to divide a string into new columns. Most articles I found divide up in new rows, that is not my goal. I am pulling the data from a Redshift db.

Here is sample string in Column 1 in CURRENT STATE:

```
Column 1='a,b,c,1,2,3'
```

Here is the DESIRED structure:

```
Column 2='a'
Column 3='b'
Column 4='c'
Column 5='1'
...
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please set the according tag.

Comment: the string format and length remains same for all rows?

Comment: "sql" here is meaningless. We need to know what RDBMS you are using (SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle, Mysql, etc). Each on has a different method of exploding/splitting a string.

Comment: @JNevill sorry, the data is queried from Amazon Redshift via SQL. And yes, string format  is the same for all columns. The length may differ though.

Comment: So if you have two records returned and one has a string with 8 comma delimited values and the other has 12 comma delimited values, how many columns would return in that result set? 8, 12, something else? This isn't something that SQL is good for since you need to know your columns in your `SELECT` clause.

Comment: @JNevill so the number of columns will be fixed. That is the good news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of columns being outputted is fixed then you can use Redshift's [`String_Part`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) function.

```
SELECT col1, 
    STRING_PART(col1, ',', 1) as Col2, 
    STRING_PART(col1, ',', 2) as Col3,
    STRING_PART(col1, ',', 3) as Col4
FROM yourtable
```

That would split `col1` from `yourtable` into 3 columns containing the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd item from the list delimited by a comma.